# error during installing ruby on rails application uninitialized constant Gem::BasicSpecification (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedena

I am trying to install ruby on rails application fedena on Ubuntu server.

It uses some old ruby library.  I followed the instructions on

http://paritosh.passion8.co.in/post/49878771105/fedena-installation-guide

```
 gem install rubygems-update -v=1.3.7
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:43:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Gem::BasicSpecification (NameError)
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1113:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1113:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require'
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
```

Comment: Fedena is not compatiable with ruby 2.3 , downgrade ruby version to 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RVM, then run

```
rvm install rubygems 1.3.7
```

this worked for me